# Accessing elements in a string?

Tags: c

I have to convert a given binary input (e.g. 1101) to decimal, but the input isn't a string array or an integer (the passed argument is `const char *binstr`).  How am I supposed to access each individual digit of the binary number so I can do pow(x,y) on each and add them together to get the decimal number?

Comment: Depends on the encoding...

Comment: Can you show a complete definition of what your input looks like?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "binary input"? Your `binstr` points to the first element of an array of `char` elements; are those characters printable digits `'0'` and `'1'`, or are they numeric values `0` and `1`, or are they something else?

Comment: I just meant that the input is a series of 0s and 1s.  In main it's initialized as `char binstr[10];`, then `scanf("%s", binstr);` and `output[i] = binTodec(binstr);` are in a for loop, calling the function, `binTodec` that I'm trying to write.  I don't really know how I can get them to be treated as integers, since I want to do binstr[1]*pow(2,2) for example which should be 1*4 = 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
binstr[0];
binstr[1];
binstr[2];
```

etc

or you can do it through a pointer

```
char* s = binstr;
unsigned long x =0;
while(*s) { x = x << 1; x |= (*s == '1' ? 1:0); s++;} 
printf("the decimal of %s is %ul", binstr, x);
```

Comment: I can't seem to get binstr[i] to give the right output though. If I try to print an element of this like printf("%d", binstr[2]);, I don't get the right output e.g. with char *binstr = "1101";, I get 49 for binstr[0], binstr[1] and binstr[3], and 48 for binstr[2].

Comment: oh, its a character  printf("%c", binstr[2]);  will print the character....  the character '1' is hex 31   ...  you could do printf("%d", binstr[2] - 0x30);  and that would give what you are expecting I think

Comment: 48 is the ASCII encoding for the character `'0'`. If `c` is either `'0'` or `'1'`, then `c - '0'` is `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`const char *` usually refers to a C string.  You can just use [`strtol(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/):

```
int x = strtol(binstr, NULL, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a `c string` and you can get each character the way similar to arrays:

`input[i]`

Here's an example of splitting the binary string into individual bits (characters) and printing them out: http://cfiddle.net/wYtKJv

You can use loops:

```
while(i<100){

if(binstr[i]== '\0'){
   break;
}

printf("First Bit:\n%c\n\n",binstr[i]);
i++;
}
```

Since C-strings are null terminated you can check to see if a character if we hit is `'\0'` to `break` the loop.

In the loop you can also convert the `chars` to `ints` and store them someplace (array probably) where you can access them for calculations.

Comment: I can't seem to get binstr[i] to give the right output though.  If I try to print an element of this like `printf("%d", binstr[2]);`, I don't get the right output

e.g. with `char *binstr = "1101";`, I get 49 for binstr[0], binstr[1] and binstr[3], and 48 for binstr[2].

Comment: I don;'t know why you chose to loop 100 times, but you should really just use `while(*ptr) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @EdS. Well, that was an exaggeration depending on how big the decimal number may be.

Comment: @Adam You're using the format `%d` which is for ints. Remember, we haven't converted to ints yet. Thus, do `printf("%c", binstr[2]);`

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; don't use the name `NULL` to refer to the null character, which is `'\0'`. I've fixed it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you. I'm afraid I'm getting to used to my IDE.

Comment: So, if for the second digit of a 4 digit binary, I do binstr[1] * pow(2,2), will it output as 1*4, or 4 or do I have to do some sort of conversion to int or something?  It's just that binstr isn't an integer, so aren't I multiplying a character/string by an integer?  Will it just know to treat the 1 as a 1 and not 49 from ascii?

Comment: no need to use pow,  computers do powers of 2 really easily via bit shifting.   the << operator does this.  so  1 << 2 will equal 4

Comment: @Adam Well don't do `binstr[1] * pow(2,2)` instead `(binstr[1]-'0') * pow(2,2)` because you need to turn char into int

Comment: Would you mind explaining how binstr[1]-'0' converts it from a char to an int?

Comment: @Adam It has to do with ASCII codes. I understand that this solution isn't fully portable, but for your purposes it seems fit.

Comment: @Cygwinnian: In fact it is fully portable; the C standard guarantees that the digits `'0'` through `'9'` have consecutive values. (It makes no such guarantee for letters, and in fact EBCDIC letters are non-consecutive). If `binstr[i]` is `'0'`, then `binstr[i] - '0'` is guaranteed to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this program which converts from Binary to Decimal

```
char *binstr = "1011011";
int   num = 0, sum = 0, ctr = 0;

ctr = strlen(binstr) - 1;
do{
    sum += ((binstr[ctr] & 0x1) << num);
    ctr--;
    num ++;
}while(ctr >= 0);
```

Comment: `(binstr[ctr] & 0x1)` makes an assumption about the numerical representation of the characters `'0'` and `'1'`. The assumption is almost certainly valid, but unless you *really* need to squeeze the last CPU cycle out of your code, it's better to be clearer.

Comment: In the question, it is mentioned that the input is a binary string. Hence, the code is written considering only 2 symbols `0` and `1`. I am not sure if I understood your point completely.

Comment: I assumed (and I still assume) that the string consists of the digits `'0'` and `'1'`, not `0` and `1`. Perhaps I'm mistaken; the question is not entirely clear.